# Refreshing API call on a few different conditions with Rxjs (Angular)

Tags: angular, rxjs

So to draw a picture, this is my current code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._pbsaAccountSelectorService.selectedAccount$.subscribe((pSelectedAccount) => {
        this.getSelectedAccountData(this._pbsaAccountSelectorService.selectedProfile.ProfileId, pSelectedAccount.AccountNumberForRequests);
    });
}
```

```
getSelectedAccountData(ProfileId: string, AccountNumberForRequests: string) {
    if(!this._rewardsService.currentSpend) {
      this._rewardsService.getCurrentSpend(ProfileId, AccountNumberForRequests).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this._rewardsService.currentSpend = res
      })
    }

    combineLatest([
      this._rewardsService.getEnigmaTransactions(AccountNumberForRequests),
      this.refresher$,
    ]).pipe(
      map(([val]) => val),
      takeUntil(this._pbsaAccountSelectorService.selectedAccount$),
    ).subscribe(res => {
      this.transactionList = res;
      this.filteredTransactionList = res;
    })
  }
```

The intended behavior is that every time the selectedAccount$ Subject emits a value, it would fire off the getCurrentSpend and getEnigmaTransactions API calls.
But additionally to that, I also need to fire off the getEnigmaTransactions call manually under certain scenarios, like if some filter criteria changes.

To attempt to achieve this, I put the getEnigmaTransactions call in a combineLatest with a refresher subject.

The issue with that is that if the account changes, I'd need to cancel the existing combineLatest, otherwise it'll just make more and more subscriptions. So I attempted to put a takeUntil that would cancel every time the account changes, but I think what's happening is that as soon as the first selectedAccount is emitted, the entire thing just cancels and never fires again.

Admittedly, even if this implementation *did* work, I'd have probably looked for a more elegant solution, as this seems like a bad way of doing things.

How can I achieve the behavior I want? Perhaps using a SwitchMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Nested subscriptions would lead to nested data streams that will in turn lead to memory leaks when the component is destroyed.
2. Use `switchMap` to map from one observable to another.
3. I'd the usage of `combineLatest` here is redundant. If the `getEnigmaTransactions()` need to triggered in two separate instances, then decouple them. Have two separate instances where it could be triggered.

Try the following

- `iif` for conditionally returning the observable
- `forkJoin` to trigger multiple observables in parallel
- `takeUntil` with a `Subject` to close subscriptions when component is closed

```js
closed$ = new Subject<any>();
enigmaTransactions$ = (acctNum: any) => this._rewardsService.getEnigmaTransactions(acctNum);

ngOnInit() {
  this._pbsaAccountSelectorService.selectedAccount$.pipe(
    switchMap((pSelectedAccount: any) =>
      iif(
        () => (!this._rewardsService.currentSpend),
        forkJoin({
          currentSpend: this._rewardsService.getCurrentSpend(
            this._pbsaAccountSelectorService.selectedProfile.ProfileId,
            pSelectedAccount.AccountNumberForRequests
          ),
          enigmaTransactions: this.enigmaTransactions$(
            pSelectedAccount.AccountNumberForRequests
          )
        }),
        this.getEnigmaTransactions$(
          pSelectedAccount.AccountNumberForRequests
        )
      )
    ),
    takeUntil(this.closed$)      // <-- close in `onDestroy` hook
  ).subscribe({
    next: (res: any) => {
      if (!!res.currentSpend) {  // <-- `forkJoin` was triggered
        // do something
        // res.currentSpend
        // res.enigmaTransactions
      } else {                   // <-- `forkJoin` was not triggered
        // do something
      }
    },
    error: (error: any) => {
      // handle error
    }
  });
}

onFilterChange(acctNum: any) {
  this.enigmaTransactions$(acctNum).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.closed$)      // <-- close in `onDestroy` hook
  ).subscribe(
    // handle response and error
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.closed$.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** put subscribe in subscribe in RXJS, you should combine incoming streams into one that will get your data

You should put everything that should retrigger fetching data into observable, to make it reactive.

- `combileLatest` makes it so that on change of any input data, the
- `switchMap` will cancel the previous requests if filters change quicker that API can return data.

```
class MyComponent {
  readonly selectedAccount$ = new Subject<any>();
  readonly filters$ = new Subject<any>();
  readonly data$ = combineLatest([
    this.selectedAccount$,
    this.filters$
  ]).pipe(
    switchMap(([account, filters]) => {
      return fetchDataObservable(account, filters);
    }),
    //shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 }), // If this observable would be used at multiple places this will prevent fetching data twice
    //takeUntil(this.destroy), // If you would use this in other places than template only
  );
}
```

```html
<pre>{{data$ | async | json}}</pre>
```